# unable to undeploy my webapp war file from tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have deployed a webapp named "webappName.war" by putting the war file in /tomcat/webapps. Tomcat successfully extracted that and I've tested my app using "localhost:8080/webappName/..." . But a few days later I've decided to change the deployed app so I simply removed the webappName.war and /webapps/webappName . I thought that's enough to undeploy a webapp. But that old webapp still exists!!!!! I can see it's row in "/localhost:8080/manager" Application table and I can test it using "/localhost:8080/webappName" !!!!!!!
There isn't any folder or war in "tomcat/webapps" but the application exists and I can not deploy my new webapp. What should I do? I really need to undeploy that app and fill the context with another one.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing "work" directory should help

Comment: you mean remove the tomcat/work directory?

Comment: it is better to shutdown Tomcat, remove anything from "tomcat/work" dir and launch Tomcat again

Comment: ok. and now everything is gone. it returns 404 http status for "/" and 500 for any other context